# member function pointer which returns same type of member function pointer

Tags: c++, declaration, return-type, member-pointers

I'd like to declare a member function pointer in C++, that returns the same member function pointer type

This doesn't work:

```
class MyClass { 
public: 
        typedef FunctionPtr (MyClass::*FunctionPtr)(); 
}
```

Does someone know a solution?

Comment: I'd love to say use `mem_fun_ref` but I can't see how.  Nice question.

Comment: not again... Why does everyone want to do this? I've never needed anything even close to this.

Comment: @David: I'm with you on that. I remember using member pointers _once_ in 15 years of programming in C++.

Answer (score 6):

There's no way to achieve exactly that. In fact, member functions make no difference here: there's no way to declare an ordinary function that returns a pointer to its own function type. The declaration would be infinitely recursive.

In case of an ordinary function you can use the `void (*)()` type as an "universal" function pointer type (just like `void *` is often used for data types). For member function pointers that would be `void (A::*)()` type. You'd have to use `reinterpret_cast` for that purpose though. However, this usage (a round-trip conversion) happens to be the one when the behavior of `reinterpret_cast` is defined.

Of course, you'll be forced to use casts to convert the pointer to and from that type. AFAIK, there are elegant template-based solutions with an intermediate temporary template object that does the casting.

You might also want to take a look at this [GotW entry](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/057.htm).

P.S. Note, that using `void *` type as an intermediate type for function pointers is prohibited by the language. While such illegal use might appear to be "working" with ordinary function pointers, it has absolutely no chance to work with member function pointers. Member function pointers are normally non-trivial objects with size greater than the size of `void *` pointer.

Answer (score 5):

AndreyT references the best answer at [GotW #57](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/057.htm), so I might as well replicate it here:

```
class MyClass {  
public: 
        struct FunctionPtrProxy;
        typedef FunctionPtrProxy (MyClass::*FunctionPtr)();  

        struct FunctionPtrProxy
        {
               FunctionPtrProxy(FunctionPtr pp ) : p( pp ) { }
               operator FunctionPtr() { return p; }
               FunctionPtr p;
        }

}
```

Comment: I was able to get the example at GoW #57 to work. But if I add a member function to above class that just returns itself that fails to compile (gcc error: argument of type ‘MyClass::FunctionPtrProxy (MyClass::)()’ does not match ‘MyClass::FunctionPtrProxy’). @MSN could you give an example with above class where you have a member function that returns itself and where it compiles, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not possible - the return type of the function is the type of the function itself, which is not yet known, so it leads to an infinite cycle.